# R: Converting Output of two interlaced Loops into a Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Hallo I have troubles with conveting the Output of two  interlaced Loops into a Matrix. These Loops are calculating the sum of all combinations of two colmumns minimas. So in a 3 colmumns case, the sum of all the minimas of 1with1, 1with2, 1with3, 2with1, 2with2,...and so on.

This code Shows me the results, which are correct, but how can I convert this into a Matrix ?

```
    for (i in 1:ncol(InputMatrix1))
        {for ( j in 1:ncol(InputMatrix1))
        {print(colSums(pmin(InputMatrix1[,i], InputMatrix1[,j])))}
    }

[1] 1
[1] 0.6
[1] 0.7
[1] 0.6
[1] 1
[1] 0.5
[1] 0.7
[1] 0.5
[1] 1
```

My Goal is to have an Output Matrix which is :

```
     [,1]   [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1with1 1with2  1with3
[2,] 2with1 2with2  2with3
[3,] 3with1 3with2  3with3

The results for These are= 
1with1/2with2/3with3=1
1with2/2with1=0,6
1with3/3with1=0,5
2with3/3with2=0,7
```

I have tried a lot including the as.matrix function but I don't get the desired result.

I really appreciate any help you can provide ! Thank you.

The InputMatrix1 Looks like this:

```
                 [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
2016-12-02 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.00000000
2016-12-05 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.00000000
2016-12-06 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.00000000
2016-12-07 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.00000000
2016-12-08 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.00000000
2016-12-09 0.03136165 0.000000000 0.08915036
2016-12-12 0.00000000 0.016019618 0.00000000
2016-12-13 0.00000000 0.000000000 0.00000000
2016-12-14 0.05338029 0.114726774 0.01268025
2016-12-15 0.17633198 0.060615604 0.26232115
2016-12-16 0.11031648 0.085173610 0.13183337
2016-12-19 0.11706411 0.057566360 0.09535812
2016-12-20 0.09325712 0.006665265 0.11754523
2016-12-21 0.09171604 0.041281630 0.05403903
2016-12-22 0.08014103 0.067453160 0.04703658
2016-12-23 0.05892727 0.049929460 0.04630817
2016-12-27 0.03526304 0.018427273 0.00000000
2016-12-28 0.11058756 0.136396545 0.13632665
2016-12-29 0.04165344 0.140486343 0.00740110
2016-12-30 0.00000000 0.205258358 0.00000000
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `dput(InputMatrix1)` so we can reproduce your data to confirm our answers ?

Comment: Your example code will fail as `colSums` expects an array of at least two dimensions. Use `sum` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your input data

```
df <- structure(list(V2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03136165, 0, 0, 0.05338029, 
0.17633198, 0.11031648, 0.11706411, 0.09325712, 0.09171604, 0.08014103, 
0.05892727, 0.03526304, 0.11058756, 0.04165344, 0), V3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.016019618, 0, 0.114726774, 0.060615604, 0.08517361, 
0.05756636, 0.006665265, 0.04128163, 0.06745316, 0.04992946, 
0.018427273, 0.136396545, 0.140486343, 0.205258358), V4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08915036, 0, 0, 0.01268025, 0.26232115, 0.13183337, 
0.09535812, 0.11754523, 0.05403903, 0.04703658, 0.04630817, 0, 
0.13632665, 0.0074011, 0)), .Names = c("V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

## Generate the matrix to hold the results

```
mat <- matrix(NA, ncol(df), ncol(df))
```

## Loop and add the result to matrix

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
    mat[i,j] <- sum(pmin(df[,i], df[,j]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
Initialise a result matrix before the loop, then inside the loop assign the value to the corresponding index.

```
x = matrix(rep(0, ncol(InputMatrix1) * nrow(InputMatrix1)), ncol = ncol(InputMatrix1))    
for (i in 1:ncol(InputMatrix1))
        {for (j in 1:ncol(InputMatrix1))
        {x[i, j] = (colSums(pmin(InputMatrix1[,i], InputMatrix1[,j])))}
    }
```

Although I should mention that this would probably better be solved by using apply.

Comment: Hallo onnhoJ , thank you for your answer which Looks very good, but the Output Matrix shoud have the Dimension of the nxn and n=number of colmns of the InputMatrix, how can I modify your code to get this ?